# XML TO LINQ parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a simple XML, the use of XML TO LINQ analysis, but "code", "budget" data can not be in the form, tried a lot of methods, has been unable to effectively solve, ask the teacher whether you can help solve the problem, thanks for the assistance.

Main program：

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace test_1015_empl
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinqExamples linq = new LinqExamples();
        linq.GetEmployeeList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = linq.GetEmployeeList();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace test_1015_empl
{
    internal class set
    {
    }

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePosition { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCountry { get; set; }
    public Project[] Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public int ProjectBudget { get; set; }
}

public class LinqExamples
{
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        if (employeeList == null)
            LoadXML();
        return employeeList;
    }

    private void LoadXML()
    {
        employeeList =
            (
                from e in XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Employees.xml").Root.Elements("employee")
                select new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeID = (int)e.Element("id"),
                    EmployeeName = (string)e.Element("name"),
                    EmployeePosition = (string)e.Element("position"),
                    EmployeeCountry = (string)e.Element("country"),
                    Projects =
                    (
                        from p in e.Elements("projects").Elements("project")
                        select new Project
                        {
                            ProjectCode = (string)p.Element("code"),
                            ProjectBudget = (int)p.Element("budget")
                        }).ToArray()
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

}

xml：

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <id>1001</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <position>Developer</position>
  <country>USA</country>
    <projects>
        <project>
            <code>Orlando</code>
            <budget>1000</budget>
        </project>
        <project>
            <code>Rocket</code>
            <budget>7000</budget>
        </project>
    </projects>
</employee>

<employee>
    <id>1002</id>
    <name>Tomas</name>
    <position>QA</position>
<country>USA</country>
    <projects>
        <project>
            <code>Orlando</code>
            <budget>1000</budget>
        </project>
        <project>
            <code>Newman</code>
            <budget>900</budget>
        </project>
    </projects>
</employee>

<employee>
    <id>1003</id>
    <name>Marina</name>
    <position>QA</position>
<country>Russia</country>
    <projects>
        <project>
            <code>Orlando</code>
            <budget>1000</budget>
        </project>
        <project>
            <code>Newman</code>
            <budget>900</budget>
        </project>
        <project>
            <code>Rocket</code>
            <budget>7000</budget>
        </project>
    </projects>
</employee>

<employee>
    <id>1004</id>
    <name>Suzan</name>
    <position>Developer</position>
<country>England</country>
    <projects>          
        <project>
            <code>Rocket</code>
            <budget>7000</budget>
        </project>
    </projects>
</employee>

 <employee>
<id>1005</id>
<name>Lucas</name>
<position>IT</position>
<country>England</country>
<projects>
  <project>
    <code>Orlando</code>
    <budget>1000</budget>
  </project>
  <project>
      <code>Rocket</code>
      <budget>7000</budget>
    </project>
    <project>
      <code>Newman</code>
    <budget>900</budget>
  </project>
  </projects>
</employee>
</employees>
```

[image]

Output the results, less "code", "budget" data, how to use the resolution?

Comment: One of your employees has three projects. What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: In addition to @Enigmativity's question, it would be nice to see the xaml code for your datagridview, since the problem is most likely not with your XML to LINQ parsing but with how you're trying to display your data.

Comment: Good teacher:

I would like to be able to output all the data, as shown：

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6BlJrfBeE4pZ0o0ODFCaEVxTUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Good teacher:

There is an error on the previous icon, please see this one icon.
I would like to be able to output all the data, as shown

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6BlJrfBeE4pM3R5S0hHaVZjUzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would suggest you to use two DataGridView: [Master/Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews). The first displays information about the employees, and the second displays data on projects selected employee.

Comment: Has tried using two DataGridView, I have finished (only a piece of data to test), but how to synthesize two DataGridView into a form

How to use C # ToArray (), ToList (), how to make them perfect together


Divide into two DataGridView graphs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6BlJrfBeE4pLWJrdHVpQ1ZxbXM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `DataGridView` with data binding as Master/Detail.

```
var employeesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
employeesBindingSource.DataSource = employeeList;

var projectsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
projectsBindingSource.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
projectsBindingSource.DataMember = nameof(Employee.Projects);

employeesDataGridView.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
projectsDataGridView.DataSource = projectsBindingSource;
```

---

See full sample:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Size = new Size(600, 400);

            var employeeList =
            (
                from e in XDocument.Load("test.xml").Root.Elements("employee")
                select new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeID = (int)e.Element("id"),
                    EmployeeName = (string)e.Element("name"),
                    EmployeePosition = (string)e.Element("position"),
                    EmployeeCountry = (string)e.Element("country"),
                    Projects =
                    (
                        from p in e.Elements("projects").Elements("project")
                        select new Project
                        {
                            ProjectCode = (string)p.Element("code"),
                            ProjectBudget = (int)p.Element("budget")
                        }).ToArray()
                }).ToList();

            var employeesDataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            var projectsDataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };

            var employeesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            employeesBindingSource.DataSource = employeeList;

            var projectsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            projectsBindingSource.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
            projectsBindingSource.DataMember = nameof(Employee.Projects);

            employeesDataGridView.DataSource = employeesBindingSource;
            projectsDataGridView.DataSource = projectsBindingSource;
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeePosition { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCountry { get; set; }
        public Project[] Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
        public int ProjectBudget { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help
May I be able to carefully the code content? Do not know how to do it correctly

I'm sorry to be a beginner, and I try to figure out the way you write

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to parse the code
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello Alexander Petrov:
I can complete your code and thank you for your help
Would you like to ask you again, if the use of a DataGridView form to write all the content is feasible.
I would like to try to write all the data in a DataGridView, if the content is null, automatically fill in "null".
Such as image content: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6BlJrfBeE4pQ3dKcUFKOWNjbUk/view?usp=sharing